# Why Router's Static Routing does not work?

Tags: routing, ftp, router, gateway, static-routes

**Background**

I have two routers, Router_A and Router_B.

Router_A LAN side IP address is `172.16.0.1`. Router_A has two clients, Computer_A (IP `172.16.0.11`) and Router_B (IP `172.16.0.2`).

Router_B WAN side IP address is `172.16.0.2`. Router_B LAN side IP address is `10.0.0.1`. Router_B has one client, FTP_Server_B (IP `10.0.0.2`).

In Router_B, the FTP ports (21, 990, and a range of predefined ports) are forwarded to `10.0.0.2`.

**Static Routing (which does not work)**

In Router_A, I have set Static Routing as follow:

```
Destination Address     Subnet Mask     Gateway     Metric
10.0.0.0                255.255.255.0   172.16.0.2  15
```

As far as I understand, this static routing rule means, within Router_A `172.16.0.xxx` subnet, when a packet needs to go to `10.0.0.xxx`, it reaches Router_A. According to the rule, `172.16.0.2` knows about `10.0.0.xxx` addresses. So Router_A will forward the packet to `172.16.0.2`.

**Problem**

From Computer_A, I try to connect to the FTP_Server_B.

1. Using `ftp://172.16.0.2`, I can login to the FTP server. Then the server replies its passive mode address `10.0.0.2`. At this point, `10.0.0.2` is unreachable and the client cannot list the directories and files.
2. Using `ftp://10.0.0.2`, I even cannot login. I even cannot reach the server.

Answer (score 0):

You have two different problems:

> Using ftp://172.16.0.2, I can login to the FTP server. Then the server replies its passive mode address 10.0.0.2.

You're port forwarding FTP in Router_B and you haven't loaded the FTP helper module(s) that will rewrite the PASV response of the FTP server to the public IP-address of Router_B (in Linux by loading the kernel module `nf_nat_ftp`) and you haven't configured your system to dynamically allow port forwarding of the data connection (in Linux with the `ip_conntrack_ftp` kernel module and allowing `--state RELATED` in your iptables rule sets).

> Using ftp://10.0.0.2, I even cannot reach the server.

Setting up the static route on Router_A for 10.0.0.0/24 should deliver those packets to 172.16.0.2, but Router_B still has to be configured accept incoming for traffic 10.0.0.0/24 on the public interface and to route those packets to your LAN.  Your question doesn't show that you have done so.

Comment: Thanks for reply! For problem (1), I use FileZilla on Win7 (unfortunately). In FileZilla, I have set it to reply with public IP addr in pasv mode. But this makes it replies the WAN side IP of Router_A. The FTP server is accessible from the Internet. I am not sure about "dynamic port forwarding". I have set FileZilla to use port 60000-65000, and forwarded these ports in Router_B. For problem (2), I did think about this is the case. But I cannot find this setting in Router_B.